# recursive function with a promise to iterative

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, promise, es6-promise

I have a function `emailIterator` which reads `messages` from a `stack` and sends them one by one using an `emailer`

I'm currently handling it recursively by calling `emailIterator` back with the same `messages` but only with one less message each time since it already got sent.

```
import { emailer } from 'pigeon';
 
interface MessageObject {
  email: string;
  recipientName: string;
  message: string;
}
 
interface  {
  error: any;
  messageAtError: MessageObject;
}
 
const data: MessageObject[] = [

  {
    email: 'bob@domain.com',
    recipientName: 'Bob',
    message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mattis.',
  },
  {
    email: 'jim@domain.com',
    recipientName: 'Jim',
    message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet mattis.',
  },
];
 
const emailIterator = (messages: MessageObject[], cb: any): void => {
  if (messages.length === 0) {
    return cb(undefined, 'All messages sent');
  } else {
    const toSend = messages.pop();
 
    emailer(toSend)
      .then(() => {
        return emailIterator(messages, cb);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        return cb({
          error: e,
          messageAtError: toSend,
        });
      });
  }
};



 
emailIterator(data, (err?: ErrorFormat, msg?: string) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('There was an error with a message:', err.messageAtError);
    console.error(err.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(msg);
});
```

I need help to transform this into an iterative solution.

here's what I came up with so far, is this right? does it handle errors efficiently? can it be done in a better way ?

```
const emailIterator2 = (messages: MessageObject[], cb: any): void => {
    for(let i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    let toSend = messages[i]; 
    try {
      const result = await emailer(toSend); 
    } catch (e: ErrorFormat) {
      return cb({
        error: e, 
        messageAtError: toSend
      })
    }
    if(i === 0) {
      return cb(undefined, 'All messages sent')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You must use `await` inside an async function: which you are not doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `async..await` inside a `for..of` loop -

```js
const emailIterator = async (messages: MessageObject[], cb: any): void => {
  let toSend
  try {
    for (const m of messages) {
      toSend = m
      await emailer(m)
    }
    cb(undefined, "All messages sent")
  }
  catch (e) {
    cb({ error: e, messageAtError: toSend })
  }
}
```

Mixing callbacks with promises has bad ergonomics. How about making `emailIterator` a promise-based function?

```js
const emailIterator = async (messages: MessageObject[]): Promise<string> => {
  let toSend
  try {
    for (const m of messages) {
      toSend = m
      await emailer(m)
    }
    return "All messages sent"
  }
  catch (e) {
    e.messageAtError = toSend
    throw e
  }
}
```

Notice the odd `toSend` assignment so it can be used in the `catch` block? Better yet is to have `emailer` throw the proper error -

```js
async function emailer(message): Promise<void> {
  try {
    // ...
  }
  catch (e) {
    e.messageAtError(message)
    throw e
  }
}
```

`emailIterator` doesn't have to worry about it now. Behaviour is the same, no `try..catch` is needed and errors bubble up as expected. Oh and TypeScript can easily infer the `Promise<string>` return type too -

```js
async function emailIterator(messages: MessageObject[]) {
  for (const m of messages)
    await emailer(m)
  return "All messages sent"
}
```